# Sort an array in ascending order according to absolute value, but show real value C programming

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, absolute-value

I'm new at programming.
This is the code that I've been trying to write, but obviously it doesn't show the original values, it prints the absolute value of the numbers of the array sorted in ascending order
Any help is appreciated!
Input example: 54 -2 6 0 82 59 22 1 -654 -21
The result I want: 0 1 -2 6 -21 22 54 59 82 -654

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main() {
    
     int array[N];
 int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < 0)
            array[i] = -array[i];
        if (array[i] > 0)
            array[i] = array[i];
    int min_idx = 0;
    min_idx = i;
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        min_idx = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            if (array[j] < array[min_idx])
            {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        if (min_idx != i)
        {
            int csere = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min_idx];
            array[min_idx] = csere;
        }
        
    }
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you're not taking a class where they disallow libraries, something like https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort can sort your array for you

Comment: @erik258 True, but the fundamental concept that the OP is missing would still remain, and that is that the comparison needs to be changed, not the input array.

Comment: @erik258 thank you, but I have to stick to these basic commands, I can already sort the array in ascending order, I just don't know how to do it with absolute values.

Comment: Don't modify the values in the array, instead when you compare them here `if (array[j] < array[min_idx])` use the absolute value of the array value.